# C code to start terminal application....?

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal

Can anyone tell me the procedure or C code to start another terminal after executing that C code. Actually I want to write a program which can start a new terminal without clicking to terminal icon. Can anybody guide me or provide me with C code.

Comment: System calls are your friends: `man execve`.

Comment: Read about [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`execl`/`execv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below C code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{

    system("gnome-terminal");
    return 0;
}
```

system() function will run the terminal command's you can run any linux command using the 
system function in the C code.

Comment: You are most welcome. You can accept it so that i will get a green tick

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to execute a command in Terminal without manually interacting with a shell, including:

Choose the Shell > New Command menu item and enter a command. Leave the Run command inside a shell checkbox unselected. Your program will be executed directly without a shell. If you open the Inspector window and look at the Info pane, you’ll see the list of processes only lists “login” and your command, but no shell.

Open a *.command file from Finder. Terminal will start a shell and tell it to execute the command file and then exit. You’ll see a shell prompt followed by a command that looks like: /path/to/your/file.command ; exit;. Again, if you look at the Inspector, the list of processes will include “login”, your shell, and your command executable. (This is also what happens if you select Run command inside a shell in the New Command panel.)

It sounds like you are using #2. There is no way to alter your program to have the shell remain interactive after your program exits; however, there are a couple of indirect ways to have Terminal run a command and then leave you with an interactive shell:

Create a settings profile that runs your command in an interactive shell:

In Preferences > Settings duplicate the default profile using the action (gear) menu at the bottom of the profiles list.
Go to the Shell pane and select Run command:.
Enter the pathname to your command file.
Select Run inside shell.
Export the settings profile to a *.terminal file, either with the Export command in the action menu, or by dragging it from the profiles list to Finder.
Then, whenever you want to create a new shell that starts by running your program, open the *.terminal file. You can also just open a new terminal with this profile from inside Terminal, either using the Shell > New Window [or Tab] menu, or by double-clicking the profile in the profile list.

Write an AppleScript that directs Terminal to run your command, as if you’d entered it into the command line. You can then either store the script in the system-wide Script menu and invoke it from there, or you can save the script as an application that you can run. The script would look like this, for example:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "/path/to/your/file.command"
end tell
```